# Animation of cars going off screen | REACT | GSAP

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap

I have this code which animates cars, I am trying to keep them on the screen until  they reach the finish line. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I want to randomise the speed of each car but also let me select the winner.
Perhaps there's better libraries/apis? I would love to know best approach

I am trying to make something like this
http://online-stopwatch.com/duck-race/

Finish line img:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/egHmb.png

Track img:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjnS.jpg

````js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import trackImage from '../../public/img/track2.png';
import finishImage from '../../public/img/finishline.png';

const Race = () => {
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(true);
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);
  const [winningCar, setWinningCar] = useState(2); // Set the winning car manually
  const [raceDuration, setRaceDuration] = useState(20); // Set the race duration
  const backgroundRef = useRef(null);
  const finishLineRef = useRef(null);
  const carRefs = useRef([]);

  const cars = Array(7).fill(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const background = backgroundRef.current;
    const finishLine = finishLineRef.current;

    const finishLinePosition = finishLine.getBoundingClientRect().right;

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      paused: !isAnimating,
      onComplete: () => setIsAnimating(false), // Stop all animations when the race finishes
    });

    tl.to(background, {
      duration: raceDuration,
      backgroundPosition: '200% 0',
      ease: 'linear',
    });

    tl.fromTo(finishLine, {
      x: '110%',
    }, {
      duration: raceDuration / 5,
      x: '0%',
      ease: 'linear',
    }, "-=" + raceDuration / 5);

    cars.forEach((_, i) => {
      const car = carRefs.current[i];
      const carPosition = car.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const carFinishPosition = finishLinePosition - carPosition;

      let duration = raceDuration - (i / cars.length); // Adjust the car speed based on its index

      if (i === winningCar - 1) {
        duration = raceDuration; // Make sure the winning car is always faster
      }

      const ease = 'power1.inOut'; // Use the same easing function for all cars

      tl.fromTo(car, {
        x: '-100%',
      }, {
        duration,
        x: `${carFinishPosition}px`,
        ease,
        onComplete: () => {
          // Only set the winner if the current car is the winning car
          if (i === winningCar - 1 && !winner) {
            setWinner(car.textContent);
          }
        },
      }, "-=" + raceDuration);
    });

    return () => {
      tl.kill();
    };
  }, [isAnimating, winner, raceDuration, winningCar]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" value={raceDuration} onChange={(e) => setRaceDuration(Number(e.target.value))} />
      <div style={{
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: '300px',
        width: '500px',
        backgroundImage: `url(${trackImage})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
      }} ref={backgroundRef}>
        <div style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          right: '0',
          top: '0',
          height: '100%',
          width: '10px',
          backgroundImage: `url(${finishImage})`,
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
        }} ref={finishLineRef} />
        {cars.map((_, i) => (
          <div key={i} style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '0',
            top: `${30 + i * 10}%`,
            fontSize: '50px',
          }} ref={el => carRefs.current[i] = el}> {i+1}</div>
        ))}
        {winner && <div style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: '0',
          width: '100%',
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontSize: '24px',
        }}>The winner is {winner}</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Race;```

As you can see in code I have tried to use power.inOut and stuff to slowly move the cars. But it does not transition them smoothly and keep them on the page. The idea is that the car's can stop or even move really slow because the track image behind them is moving. Then they just have to move fast when the finish line shows.
````